# Any way in Python to perform SQL-like queries in Python objects?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have an example class:

```
class Example():

  def __init__(self, id, code, table):
    self.id = id
    self.code = code
    self.table = table
```

and three objects

```
a = Example(1,10,100)
b = Example(2,10,200)
c = Example(3,20,100)
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
s = [a,b,c]
x = sql(code = 10, s)  #x = (a,b)
x = sql(id = 3, s)  #x = (c,)
x = sql(table > 200, s)  #x = ()
```

I don't want to perform very complex queries but a suggestion of any approach is valuable as long as it is fast (That's why I don't use a filter function) and also avoids setting up an external database.

Comment: Sorry, asking for specific libraries is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You are looking for an *ORM*, an object relational mapper. Python has several, with [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) the most widely used, but do look at [other lists of Python ORMs](https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html).

Comment: This is not a question about ORMs! This is a question about filtering. The way the question is phrased is unfortunate (e.g. asking for a specific library), but I don't see this as off-topic.

Comment: You can ask this in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @asthasr: the way that this is worded *makes it off-topic*. But I see now that I misread this, so my list of recommendations doesn't apply. Oh well. I found a duplicate for the 'query Python objects' case.